# android & libgdx - how to use resources only once for both desktop and android projects?

Tags: android, image, resources, assets, libgdx

i'm a little new to libgdx library (opengl wrapper library) under android .
i've noticed that the examples have the same resources files (images) on both the desktop and android projects.

is there a way to have those files reside on one project (even an additional ,library project)  so that both the android and the desktop projects will use it?
maybe have a linking of resources of some kind?
in short, does anyone know of the best practice of this problem?

### could libgdx even handle any folder that is not in the assets folder of an android project?

ok , the sortest answer i got is that , assuming that both desktop and android projects are on the same folder :
go to the desktop project ->java build path->source -> linked source ->path variables-> put "PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/ANDROID_PROJECT_FOLDER/assets" .
and then , from now on , put the assets files only inside the android project.